# How to install DBI and other modules on msysgit (on Windows 7)?

Tags: perl, cpan, dbi, msysgit

I'm trying to install the DBI perl module on my Windows 7 machine, using Git for Windows, ie. msysgit, and the version of perl that ships with it.

I've been able to install a few other perl modules, but when I try to install DBI (via `perl -MCPAN -e "install DBI"`), the build process bombs out with the following error:

```
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" "/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap "/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/typemap" -typemap "typemap"  Perl.xs > Perl.xsc && mv Perl.xsc Perl.c

gcc -c   -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DUSEIMPORTLIB -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe   -DVERSION=\"1.636\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.636\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE"  -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wno-comment -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-unused-parameter Perl.c

In file included from DBIXS.h:23:0,
             from Perl.xs:7:
C:/git-sdk-64/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE/perl.h:805:25: fatal error: sys/wait.h: No such file or directory
      #   include <sys/wait.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:627: Perl.o] Error 1
 TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
 /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

I get a similar error when I try to install Text::CSV_XS.

Based on what I've read elsewhere, I'm assuming that I'm missing something in my build environment. I've installed all the [development metapackages mentioned on the msysgit documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/Contributing%20to%20MSYS2/) without any luck.

I'm not opposed to somehow building the module without using cpan, but I don't know how to troubleshoot the error I'm getting, let alone take on building something new. Suggestions?

Comment: msysgit provides a package, installable via pacman for DBI:

    `pacman -S perl-DBI`

However, that doesn't solve the wider problem of what's missing, preventing cpan from installing other modules like Text::CSV_XS or whatever else I'll later need.

Comment: It seems msysgit does not provide a full build environment.

Comment: Have you tried using `Cygwin`?  I have DBI as well as Text::CSV_XS installed there without any issues.

Comment: Or maybe try Active Perl, which has ppm, the perl package manager. It downloads prebuilt binaries, instead of trying to compile C code (XS) that some modules use..

Comment: Or use Strawberry Perl: both ActiveState Perl and Strawberry have a full working CPAN client and allow you to compile using MSYS just about anything. Also Strawberry has loads of modules, such as DBI and your favourite database drivers, preinstalled.

Comment: Today's slog will be getting msysgit to use Strawberry Perl (what I've used without heartache in the past) instead of the built in perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysysgit does not provide a full build environment. Thus, the best solution is to install another version of Perl (Strawberry Perl or Active Perl, for example) and alter your path so that mysysgit uses that perl rather than the one that comes built in.

Answer (score 0):

I have Git-for-Windows SDK installed along with Strawberry Perl.  I use this bash function (your Strawberry Perl installation dir may be different):

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo sperl
function sperl {
    local pargs=("$@") PP="/c/Strawberry" # PP="$HOME/SwPerl64/ZIP"
    (
    export PATH="$PP/c/bin:$PP/perl/site/bin:$PP/perl/bin:$PATH"
    perl "${pargs[@]}"
    )
}
```

I also have something like this in my path as `sperl.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
#
function sperl {
    local pargs=("$@") PP="/c/Strawberry" # PP="$HOME/SwPerl64/ZIP"
    (
    export PATH="$PP/c/bin:$PP/perl/site/bin:$PP/perl/bin:$PATH"
    perl "${pargs[@]}"
    )
}
#
sperl "$@"
```

This allows scripts like this:

```
#!/bin/env sperl.sh
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Hello World!\n";
```